# Retrieve navigation properties's data in a recently added record

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 3 entities in my case. Invoice, InvoiceDetail and Item.
Invoice has a collection of InvoiceDetail.And each InvoiceDetail has an Item.

Please see the code below:

```
var ctx = new TestEntities();

var newInvoice = new Invoice
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        UserId = 14
    };

newInvoice.InvoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetail
    {
        ItemId = 345,
        ItemCount = 10
    });
newInvoice.InvoiceDetails.Add(new InvoiceDetail
{
    ItemId = 534,
    ItemCount = 10
});

ctx.Invoices.Add(newInvoice);
ctx.SaveChanges();

// workaround
// ctx.Items.ToList(); 

foreach (var i in newInvoice.InvoiceDetails)
{
    // In this line I get NullReferenceException
    Console.WriteLine(i.Item.Title);
}
```

I get NullReferenceException when I want to retrieve each InvoiceDetail's Item data.

The problem is solved when I uncomment, commented part of the code. (ctx.Items.ToList())

**UPDATE 1 :**

And also this is the Item class:

```
public partial class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            this.InvoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public partial class InvoiceDetail
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public long ItemId { get; set; }
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }

        public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your `Item` Class (the others probably wouldn't hurt either)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `InvoiceDetail`, although both are useful, my bad.

Comment: @Chris I added 2 updates in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NOTE: I am assuming EF5]

The problem could be related to the way you create instances of `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetail`. You are `new`ing up instances so they are not EF proxies with all of the necessary components for lazy loading.

I suggest you try using the `DbSet.Create()` method instead of `new`

```
var newInvoice = ctx.Set<Invoice>().Create();
newInvoice.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
newInvoice.UserId = 14;


var detail1 = ctx.Set<InvoiceDetail>().Create();
detail1.ItemId = 345;
detail1.ItemCount = 10;
newInvoice.InvoiceDetails.Add(detail1);

//...
```

I can't promise this will fix your problem as EF is such an intricate and varied beast but it is worth giving this a try ...

Comment: OMG bro! Really tnx @qujck .Would you explain me how this method works in my case?

Comment: @RezaAhmadi calling `Create()` gives a fully fledged EF Proxy with lazy loading etc. When you `new` up a class and add it the `Context` the class instance (e.g. `newInvoice`) will not get wrapped by a proxy. As @Chris has correctly noted below, calling `ToList()` pulled all of the `Items` into the `Context` and EF was smart enough to find them locally and attach them to `newInvoice` but was not smart enough to look in the database (possibly because `ctx` knew that `newInvoice` was not in the database yet?).